# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. help im beginner

Tags: python

```
def task(n):
    my_sum = 0
    for my_sum in range(my_sum,n+1,1):
        print(sum(my_sum))
```

here is my problem,
i want to sum all of the list in range but always error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
can u help me

Comment: `my_sum` is a single integer.  It makes no sense to call `sum()` on one integer.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Reading the `sum` documentation will readily solve this problem.

Comment: Also note that you've used `my_sum` as a normal variable, a loop variable, *and* a list.

Comment: If you intended to sum up the numbers between my_sum and n+1, you can call `sum()` directly on the range:  `sum(range(my_sum, n+1, n))`

Answer (score 0):

sum() is an inbuilt function. The input should be an iterable(eg: list).

Docs link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

```
def task(n):
    my_sum = 0
    for my_sum in range(my_sum,n+1,1):
        my_sum+=my_sum
    return my_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `my-sum` is an integer. You can not iterate an integer over a list.

`def sumList(list):
   sum = 0
   for value in list:
     sum += value
   return sum`

Or the more idiomatic way:
`sum(list)`
Which is an inbuilt function